# Getting null error when reading configuration from appsettings.json in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I created a simple ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application in which I am just reading values from the `appsettings.json` file.

In my `appsettings`, I created two sections `SectionA` and `SectionB`:

```
{
  "SectionA": {
    "SectionASubItem1": "test value",
    "SectionASubItem2": "test value2"
  },
  "SectionB": {
    "SectionBSubItem1": "test value",
    "SectionBSubItem2": "test value2"
  }
}
```

I also created a class to map this value with class properties:

This is what my `MyConfiguration` class looks like:

```
public class MyConfiguration
{
    public SectionA SectionA { get; set; }
    public SectionB SectionB { get; set; }
}

public class SectionA
{
    public string SectionASubItem1 { get; set; }
    public string SectionASubItem2 { get; set; }
}

public class SectionB
{
    public string SectionBSubItem1 { get; set; }
    public string SectionBSubItem2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the `program.cs` class I created a variable type of `IConfigurationRoot` in which I am storing the JSON file properties:

```
var myConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();
```

and mapping the section like this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<SectionA>(myConfiguration.GetSection("SectionA"));
builder.Services.Configure<SectionB>(myConfiguration.GetSection("SectionB"));
```

The problem is when I am reading the `sectionA` and `sectionB` inside the controller I am getting null. Due to this, I am not getting values from JSON file.

```
public readonly MyConfiguration configuration;

public WeatherForecastController()
{
    configuration = new MyConfiguration();
}

[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    // Here I am getting null
    var sectionA = configuration.SectionA;

    if (sectionA == null)
        return BadRequest();

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `new MyConfiguration()` in the controller's constructor returns the  `myConfiguration ` object?

Comment: Why are you doing this - `configuration = new MyConfiguration();`? Please read the documentation, especially [ASP.NET Core one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `appsetting.json` like this:

```
"MyConfiguration": {
    "SectionA": {
      "SectionASubItem1": "test value AAAAAA",
      "SectionASubItem2": "test value2 AAAA"
    },
    "SectionB": {
      "SectionBSubItem1": "test value BBBBBB",
      "SectionBSubItem2": "test value2 BBBBBB"
    }
  }
```

Then in `Program.cs` configure like this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<SectionB>(myConfiguration.GetSection("MyConfiguration"));
```

The most important point is don't `new MyConfiguration()` in your Constructor, you need to use `dependency injection` to set the value.

```
private readonly IOptions<MyConfiguration> _configuration;

public WeatherForecastController(IOptions<MyConfiguration> configuration)
{
    _configuration= configuration;
}
```

**Then you can get the value in _configuration:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

in appsettings.json

```
 "test": {
        "MyConfiguration": {
          "SectionA": {
            "SectionASubItem1": "test value",
            "SectionASubItem2": "test value2"
          },
          "SectionB": {
            "SectionBSubItem1": "test value",
            "SectionBSubItem2": "test value2"
          }
        }
      }
```

in programm.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(myConfiguration.GetSection("test:MyConfiguration"));
```

and then

```
private readonly MyConfiguration _myConfiguration;

public WeatherForecastController(IOptions<MyConfiguration> options)
{
    _myConfiguration = options.Value;
}

var sectionA = _myConfiguration.SectionA; bla bla
```

it is better to use IOptions,IoptionsSnapshot, or IOptionsMonitor.

> [Difference between IOptionsMonitor vs. IOptionsSnapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788988/difference-between-ioptionsmonitor-vs-ioptionssnapshot)